# CSV file header

Tags: plugins, categories, csv

What would be the CSV file header, (to import into WordPress), to show the category and subcategory of each post, and how would be the content, for that header?

I´m using the plugin "[CSV Importer](http://wordpress.org/plugins/csv-importer/)".

Comment: That plugin seems to be quite out of date have you considered using the more up to date http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to considering using the [WP Ultimate CSV Importer Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/) instead with this you can map the different fields in the CSV to the columns in wordpress

[image: Import Date Configuration]
<sub>(source: [wordpress.org](https://s.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/screenshot-2.png?r=763305))</sub>

Comment: Hi. I`ve tried Ultimate CSV Importer, CSV Importer worked better for me. So if anyone have any idea of how could I use, the content of "csv_post_categories", so I can display the category and subcategory of its post, I would be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn´t seems there´s an easy way:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-csv-importer-import-sub-category